# android InAppPurchases list latest purchases

Tags: php, android, google-api, in-app-purchase

I've been checking Google's API to get the information about the developer payload (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products) but it requires the purchase token, and i can get this token only if i access the wallet and list all the transactions, but i want to make this automatically.
Is there a way to pull the purchases by date range and from there, collect the token for every purchase and also the developer payload, or at least the token?

I am using php library and i am able to pull the detail for 1 purchase.